# jQuery click and drag 3 times to trigger event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, click, drag

I'm trying to figure out how I could trigger an event which after click and drag 3 times over element would trigger an event. The scenario is rubbing the 'Alladin's lamp' (I know) - when you click and drag left / right / left or right / left / right - something happens after that.

I don't really know where to start other than just trigger the click() event and then perhaps drag using jQuery UI - just a guess - any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: looks like you want mouse gesture support. i didn't try it, but maybe this is suitable: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-event-special-gesture/

Comment: Thanks Alp - I'll give it a try too.

Answer (score 2):

You should read jQuery UI [draggable documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). You could use the [dragstop event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-stop).
A fast example : 
Construct one element `lamp` and (for example) another element `hand`. When you drag the `hand` hover the `lamp`, you can store in a boolean variable if your `hand` have really hovered the `lamp`. If `true` when `dragstop`, so you can increment another variable which contains the number of times of the `hand` hover the `lamp`. Then, if this number is equal to 3, show the genius :) !

Answer (score 1):

Ok - found the solution - this plugin does the great job: [Jquery Gestures](http://www.jsplugins.com/Scripts/Plugins/View/Jquery-Gestures/)

Thanks everyone!